# How can I ignore map property in NHibernate with setter

Tags: nhibernate, properties, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I need to ignore map property with setter in NHibernate, because the relationship between entities is required. This is my simple model

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual Guid PersonId { get; set; }

    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }

    public virtual string SecondName { get; set; }

    //this is the property that do not want to map
    public Credential Credential { get; set; }
}

public class Credential
{
    public string CodeAccess { get; set; }

    public bool EsPremium { get; set; }
}

public sealed class PersonMap : ClassMapping<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Table("Person");
        Cache(x => x.Usage(CacheUsage.ReadWrite));
        Id(x => x.Id, m =>
        {
            m.Generator(Generators.GuidComb);
            m.Column("PersonId");
        });

        Property(x => x.FirstName, map =>
        {
            map.NotNullable(true);
            map.Length(255);
        });
        Property(x => x.SecondName, map =>
        {
            map.NotNullable(true);
            map.Length(255);
        });


    }

}
```

I know that if I leave the property Credential {get;} I was not going to take the map of NHibernate, but I need to set the value in my bussiness logic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but you can try this out:

```
Property(x => x.Credential, map => map.Access(Accessor.None));
```

Comment: thanks but now it throws the following error Could not determine type for: MyApp.Credential, MyApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(Credential)

Answer (score 0):

Just make it a read only property

```
Property(x => x.Credential, map => map.Access(Accessor.ReadOnly));
```

Comment: thanks but now it throws the following error Could not determine type for: MyApp.Credential, MyApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(Credential)